# Tracker GV500 - Device management

Tags: cumulocity

I currently registered my Quecklink GV500 to cumulocity and I'm able to receive some events and measurements.

But when I try to send command to my Quecklink GV500 registered in Cumulocity but I always hava a FAILED response. For example, I tried to send this command (which is fully supported by the GV500) from SHELL tab: `AT+GTTMA=gv500,+,1,0,0,,,,,,FFFF$`

And as result I got:

> Failure reason:   Command currently not supported

I also tried to get the agent logs by using "Log file request" in the "Log" tab of my Device and as result I got:

> Failure reason:   Cannot build command. Search parameters only allow the
>   following characters [a-zA-Z0-9_]

Is it normal?

When I look the general information in "Info" tab I have:

- Send connection: online
- Push connection: inactive

Is it normal that Push connection is marked as inactive?

Answer (score 0):

The tracker-agent in it current state does not use a push connection for receiving operations but does a polling of the operations. Therefore the push connection is always shown as inactive.

If you receive "Failure reason: Command currently not supported" it is an error from the agent not the device. The agent seems not to support shell operations for Queclink.

As for the error on the log file request it seems that there was an unsupported character in the search parameter. Maybe you can share what you entered for the parameters in the UI

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. For the log file request I let blank value in the search input field. If I try to enter "gl200", I get the following error: `Command currently not supported`.

So to resume can you confirm that Quecklink devices can't be managed from Cumulocity for the moment? It's supported for which device?